# How to update UI from child tasks in WinForms

Tags: winforms, task-parallel-library

I've got a simple little winforms app that performs a long running process on another thread via a TPL Task.  During this long running process I'd like to update the UI (the progress bar or something).  Is there a way to do this without being required to .ContinueWith()?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Task _childTask;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            // Do some work
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            // Update the UI
            _childTask.Start();

            // Do more work
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        });

        _childTask = new Task((antecedent) =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            textBox1.Text = "From child task";
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());


    }
}
```

Executing this code I get the ubiquitous exception:

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'textBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: I think you have to paste the textbox reference to the thread.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, you can explicitly call [`BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx) on the Window/Control that you want to communicate with. In your case this would look like this:

```
this.textBox.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
{
   this.textBox.Text = "From child task.";
}));
```

Comment: That definitely looks to be on the way but I get a compilation error: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: I created an Action and passed in the action instead of the anonymous method.  Not sure why the above doesn't work but it got me 99% of the way there.  Thanks Drew.

Comment: @devlife Oops, that's my fault for being so used to just working with newer APIs. Yes, you need to explicitly wrap with a new Action(...) because of the way the signature of the old WinForms BeginInvoke API was designed. I will update my answer.

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You're passing the `TaskScheduler` as `state` (or `antecedent`, as you called it). That doesn't make much sense.

I'm not sure what exactly do you want to do, but you need to specify the `TaskScheduler` when you're starting the `Task`, not when you're creating it. Also, it seems that `childTask` doesn't have to be a field:

```
var scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

Task childTask = null;

Task.Factory.StartNew(
    () =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        childTask.Start(scheduler);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    });

childTask = new Task(
    () =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        textBox1.Text = "From child task";
    });
```

Of course, all this is going to be much easier with C# 5 and `await`:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    StartAsync();
}

private async void StartAsync()
{
    // do some work
    await Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(1000); });

    // start more work
    var moreWork = Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(1000); });

    // update the UI, based on data from “some work”
    textBox1.Text = "From async method";

    // wait until “more work” finishes
    await moreWork;
}
```

You can't make `async` constructor, but you can run an `async` method from it. “Doing work” doesn't run on the UI thread, because it was started explicitly through `Task.Run()`. But since `StartAsync()` was called directly, it executes on the UI thread.

Comment: That's just the point.  I don't want to wait until one task is completed to execute the other.

Comment: I updated my example to better show what I was trying to get across.

Comment: In that case, my first sample will still work for you. I also updated the C# 5 version.

Comment: That is pretty much what I was trying to do (just didn't get it quite right).  Can't wait to start using C#5....